# How to use groupBy in Backbone.js to group collections?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

An example collection (showing models only):

```
[
    {
        name: "Bob"
        date: "Thu Mar 29 2012"
    },
    {
        name: "James"
        date: "Fri Mar 30 2012"
    },
    {
        name: "Dylan"
        date: "Fri Mar 30 2012"
    },
    {
        name: "Stanley"
        date: "Sat Mar 31 2012"
    },
]
```

How can I use Underscore.js' groupBy function to group models with the same date?

Comment: You forgot the commas before `date:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `_.groupBy(data, 'date');`

You could also use pass a custom function, but in this case it's not necessary as the attribute shortcut syntax above works fine.

```
_.groupBy(data, function(row) {
    return row.date;
});
```

**Demo:**

```
> _.groupBy(data, 'date')
{ 'Thu Mar 29 2012': [ { name: 'Bob', date: 'Thu Mar 29 2012' } ],
  'Fri Mar 30 2012':
   [ { name: 'James', date: 'Fri Mar 30 2012' },
     { name: 'Dylan', date: 'Fri Mar 30 2012' } ],
  'Sat Mar 31 2012': [ { name: 'Stanley', date: 'Sat Mar 31 2012' } ] }
> _.groupBy(data, function(row) { return row.date });
{ 'Thu Mar 29 2012': [ { name: 'Bob', date: 'Thu Mar 29 2012' } ],
  'Fri Mar 30 2012':
   [ { name: 'James', date: 'Fri Mar 30 2012' },
     { name: 'Dylan', date: 'Fri Mar 30 2012' } ],
  'Sat Mar 31 2012': [ { name: 'Stanley', date: 'Sat Mar 31 2012' } ] }
>
```

Comment: Is there a way to set up views for each group and keep automatically sync those views as one model moves from one group to another? For example, if I change the date on a model, it should be moved to another group and the views would have to update accordingly. Any way to do this semi-automatically (perhaps using Marionette) or will I have to do this manually?

Comment: This doesn't work for actual backbone collections, the answer by bullfrog is correct.

Answer (score 52):

If you are grouping an actual backbone collection you can use the backbone method groupBy which implicitly uses underscore _.groupBy functionality.  This is a much cleaner approach in my opinion.

```
collection.groupBy( function(model){
  return model.get('date');
});
```

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question asked.

Comment: This is the answer that describes how to group by using backbone. The answers above describe hot to group by using underscore

Comment: You could even use the shorthand : collection.groupBy('date')

Comment: @IanS maybe your property name is not correct, hard to know the reason without any infos

Comment: Thanks, but I suspect that most likely I'm using an older version of Backbone... The full code in this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

ThiefMaster answer is perfectly valid, but it caused me some confusion because I was searching a solution for a backbone.js collection as the title indicates.

If the question object is a backbone collection we should do the following to group the models by date:

```js
_.groupBy(collection.models, function(model){
    return model.get('date')
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This is also the actual answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

```
var groups =collection.groupBy(function(model) { return model.get('date'); });

//iterate over groups
for(date in groups) { 
    var models = groups[date];
    console.log('date: '+date); 
    for (var model_idx in models) {  
        console.log('    name: '+ models[model_idx].get('name'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.3#method) instead of underscore, you can achieve the same result using the `_.method()` accessor,

```
collection.groupBy(_.method('get', 'date'));
```