# How to find unique part of sting in array of strings?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of addresses:

1. Flat 1, Some Road, Town, Postcode
2. Flat 2, Some Road, Town, Postcode
3. Flat 3, Some Buidling, Some Road, Town, Postcode
4. Flat 4, Some Road, Town, Postcode

Or like this:

1. Flat 1, Town, Postcode
2. Flat 2, Town, Postcode
3. Flat 3, Some Buidling, Town, Postcode
4. Flat 4, Town, Postcode

I don't know how long the unique or same part of the string is.

I want to be able to work out the unique part of the address and display it once with the other parts remaining separately so it would look like this:

Some Road, Town, Postcode (or Town, Postcode for the second example)

1. Flat 1
2. Flat 2
3. Flat 3, Some Buidling
4. Flat 4

I have tried using an object, then _.pluck and _.uniq to test if that item is unique but if fails for the item 3 above which isn't in line with the other items.

Comment: Unless your input is **extremely** well massaged this is going to start failing as soon as one item is formatted a little bit differently than all the others. Are you sure it's a good idea?

Comment: Where exactly does your input come from? Could you build it up as you go, or is it all grabbed at one time?

Comment: its coming from a database - the issue is that the objects don't line up - i can process one at a time if there is a solution for that

Comment: are they all and ALWAYS separated by commas?

Comment: @DanieleB yes - that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the separator is always a comma, here is a possible solution

1. transform each array element into an array of elements
2. for each address create a model with two attributes {unique_address:"", changing_info:""}. The unique_address attribute is composed by the last three elements of the array.

.

```
var modelList=[];

_.each(addresses, function(element){
   var addrArr= addresses[element].split("");  //= ["Flat 1", "Some Road", "Town", "Postcode"];
   var len=addrArr.length;
   var uniq=addrArr[len-1]+" "+addrArr[len-2]+" "+addrArr[len-3]; //uniq= "Some Road Town Postcode"
   var chang="";
   for (var i=0;i<(len-3);i+){
         chang=chang+addrArr[i];
         } //which gives chang="Flat 1"
   modelList.push({unique_address:uniq, changing_info:chang});
   });
```

Now you have list of object like this:

```
modelList=[{unique_address: "Some Road Town Postcode", changing_info: "Flat 1"},
{unique_address: "Some Road Town Postcode", changing_info: "Flat 2"},
{unique_address: "Some Road Town Postcode", changing_info: "Flat 45"}];
```

Having a list like that, you have several ways to obtain what you want.

I suggest to use `_.groupBy(list, iterator)`  which is built in in underscore.js
Like this:

```
_.groupBy(modelList, function(element) {
    return element.unique_address;
});
```

that's all.

for more information on use of groupby see [How to use groupBy in Backbone.js to group collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954597/how-to-use-groupby-in-backbone-js-to-group-collections)

Comment: the problem is that i don't know that it is the last three elements - in some cases it might be the last four in others the last two.

Comment: You should think about this: how do you realize that they are the last 3 or 2 or 4...? Try to analyze it, the step you make to understand which is the fixed address, and then we'll try to translate it into a machine understandable langauge :-)

Comment: that is the point of the question - how do i find the unique part of a string compared to the common parts!

Comment: I can help you if you give some examples. In the examples you posted the pattern is always the same, that is to say the last three cells are the fixed part of the address. which are the other cases?

Comment: hello there...any news from mars?

Comment: What if you just give back the `Town, Postcode` ?

In any case, if you get familiar with groupby you can run nested groupby and get the result you search for.

If you need an example I can update my answer or writing a new one.